# How to get role on Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway and one Microservice

I am using OAuth2 with Keycloak

API Gateway is my OAuth2 Client and it serves secure pages and redirect request to microservice

I need to authorize access to renderer one page "/backoffice", but when i use hasRole method to authorize the user a receive Access Denied.

It occurs because keycloak generates access token with the pattern:

[Access Token from Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMFSk.png)

It is my Gateway SecurityWebFilterChain

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        
        http.csrf().disable();
        
        http.
            authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/backoffice/**").hasRole("approver")
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .oauth2Client();
        
        return http.build();
        
    }
}
```

I tried to use the same approach used by Microservice but I receive 401 Unauthorized... I tried to use @Order to have two filter but not works

```
  // Microservice's SecurityWebFilterChain
    @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> 
                    exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/{id}/decision").hasRole("ROLE_user")
                        .anyExchange().permitAll())
                        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                            oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())));      
            
            return http.build();
        }
        
        Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {
            JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter =
                    new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
            
            jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor());
            
            return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
        }
        
        static class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    
            @Override
            public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
                
                var realm_access = (Map<String, List<String>>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Collections.emptyMap());
                
                return realm_access.get("roles").stream()
                    .map(role -> "ROLE_".concat(role))
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            
        }
```

Can I have both in same application, is there conflict?